# Is the axiom of countable choice equivalent to the statement that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset?

Tags: set-theory

Assume ZF.  A more general version of this question is the following. Given the three statements

1. Axiom of countable choice
2. Every infinite set has a countably infinite subset
3. Infinite implies Dedekind-infinite

we know that 1 implies 2 and 2 implies 3.  However can anyone prove either reverse implication (in ZF), or else has anyone heard of a model where 3 holds but but not 2, or where 2 holds but not 1?

Comment: Statements 2 and 3 are the same because Dedekind-infinite = has a countably infinite subset.

Comment: What is your definition of an infinite set?

Comment: @ErikD The correct definition of infinite set in set theory is "a set not in bijection with any finite ordinal." When working under the axiom of choice we can fudge this, but in $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone this is the definition of "infinite" that is used.

Comment: The wikipedia entry for Dedekind-infinite set claims that "the equivalence of the two definitions [infinite respectively Dedekind-infinite] is strictly weaker than the axiom of countable choice (CC)", but no specific reference is given.

Comment: That infinite sets are Dedekind infinite does not imply countable AC. This is problem 8.3.4 in Jech's AC book. He attributes this result to Pincus, who proved it in his dissertation.